# How many pairwise copulas in a $k$-dimensional R-vine?

Tags: copula, vine-copula

I am studying R-vine copulas. Let $k$ denote the number of random variables the joint distribution of which we are modeling. R-vine breaks down the $k$-variate copula into $K$ bivariate copulas. I am trying to understand how $K$ is related to $k$.

**Question:** How many pairwise copulas are there in a $k$-dimensional R-vine?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, $K=k(k-1)/2$.

The tree structure in Figure 1 of Dissmann et al. (2013) illustrates that an R-vine is represented by $k-1$ trees that have $k-1,k-2,\dots,1$ edges, respectively, where each edge stands for a pair copula. This is an arithmetic progression the sum of which is: $(k-1)+(k-2)+\dots+1=k(k-1)/2$.
(My uncertainty is, is this the general case, or is it just a special case. It seems to me it is the general case.)

**Reference**

- Dissmann et al. ["Selecting and estimating regular vine copulae and application to financial returns"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167947312003131) (2013) (arXiv version [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2002)).

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Kindly note that `k(k-1)/2` is the rule for all vine copula models. However, and especially for high dimensional data, you may need to reduce the complexity of the model by truncating the vine model.

Comment: @Maryam, thank you!